# How to create a background color based border in a circle div?

Tags: html, css

I tried to create a circle which `border` should look same color as div color and a space between the border and div. The in between space should show the background color of what ever div it is on. the background color is changeable so we shouldn't hardcode it.

Instead i have given transparency using `rgba` mode. All work fine am trying to get this effect on hover of the circle but i couldn't able to get the hover because i'm trying to `display:block` on hover and in normal state it is `display:none;` This are for the after selector hence i tried this effect with after selector.

CODE
CSS

```
.main{
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    border-radius:100%;
    background-color:#007eff;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:80px;

}
.main:hover + .main:after{
    display:block;

}
.main:after{
      width:86px;
    height:86px;
    border-radius:100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    border:2px solid #007eff;
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    z-index:-1;
    top:3px;
    left:3px;
   display:none;
}
body{
    background-color:#888;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="main"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i>
</div>
```

[PROBLEM STATE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ku6BQ/)
ON HOVER it should become like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/Ku6BQ/1/) with effects if possible
If there is any tutorial to do this i'll happy to learn. Thanks

Comment: you mean this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/Ku6BQ/15/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set `position:relative;` to the `.main` and set `left/right/top/bottom` of the `.main:after` to zero and add `transition:all ease 0.3s` for animating.

in the `.main:hover:after` change `left/right/top/bottom` to `-5px`.

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/Ku6BQ/22/)

```
.main{
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    border-radius:100%;
    background-color:#007eff;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:80px;
    position:relative;
    margin:6px;
}

.main:after{
    border-radius:100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    border:2px solid #007eff;
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    z-index:-1;
    top:0px;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
     transition:all ease 0.3s;
}
.main:hover:after{
    top:-5px;
    bottom:-5px;
    right:-5px;
    left:-5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks +1. This is what i'm looking for. can i know how it can be done. @Mohsen

Answer (score 4):

Just add `.main:hover:after` to display it as `block` on hover [WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ku6BQ/13/)

```
.main:hover:after{
    display:block; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the exact selector. +1

Comment: Sorry i accepted Mohsen answer which is what am exactly looking for. Even though selector you given Helps me. You are almost accepted. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

**CSS :**

```
.main{
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    border-radius:100%;
    background-color:#007eff;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:80px;

}
.main:hover:after{
      width:86px;
    height:86px;
    border-radius:100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    border:2px solid #007eff;
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    z-index:111;
    top:3px;
    left:3px;

}
body{
    background-color:#888;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<div class="main"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i>
</div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/Ku6BQ/16/)

Answer (score 2):

you could use box-shadow instead pseudo-element :
http://jsfiddle.net/Ku6BQ/24/

```
.main {
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    border-radius:100%;
    background-color:#007eff;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:80px;
}
.main:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #888888, 0 0 0 6px #007eff;
}
body {
    background-color:#888;
```

}
If you it it transparent and show behind a gradient or an image, you may still use box-shadow : http://jsfiddle.net/Ku6BQ/25/ http://jsfiddle.net/Ku6BQ/26/

```
.main {
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    border-radius:100%;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 100px #007eff;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:80px;
}
.main:hover {
    border:4px transparent solid;
    margin:-4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #007eff,
        inset 0 0 0 100px #007eff;;
}
html {
    background :#888 url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature) repeat;
height:100%;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks +1 for the alternative trick. but i think it won't give the background divs colors in the gap

Comment: body background-color is #888888 and first box-shadow is #88888 , same colors used :)

Comment: actually, the best would be to have something transparent, so you see through the background, either a gradient or an image  http://jsfiddle.net/Ku6BQ/25/ http://jsfiddle.net/Ku6BQ/26/

Comment: thanks. I can able to see the background. Different trick. I didn't have much aware in box-shadow. i'll try to learn. again +1. Really different

Comment: it is not a trick, you can draw as many shadows as wanted on one element, with blur or not :)

Comment: Okay.Thanks for the info. I'll use it when ever possible

Comment: I couldn't understand this. how we can able to see the background. Because the border is always sticked to the div, there won't be any separation. Can you explain this if you have time. Thanks

Comment: i use a transparent border (tranparent or rgba(x,x,x,0) ) , and shadow inside and outside , so you can see through the border. if you use background-color instead box-shaow:inset 0 0 0 XXpx , background is drawn too behind the border and do not llow to see what's behind.

Answer (score 1):

An improvement (just for the record) on he idea of a box shadow as apported by GCyrillus

```
.main {
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    border-radius:100%;
    background-color:#007eff;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:80px;
    border: solid 4px transparent;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px white;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.main:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px #007eff;
}
body {
    background-color:#888;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ku6BQ/27/)